# Missing scene from Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs

Tags: alternate-version, snow-white-and-the-seven-dwarfs

Excerpt from the Wikipedia page of Disney's [Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Seven_Dwarfs_(1937_film)#Story_development):

> ... several sequences featuring the dwarfs were cut from the film. (...) Another, also completely animated, would have shown the **dwarfs eating soup noisily and messily**; Snow White unsuccessfully attempts to teach them how to eat 'like gentlemen'. A partially animated sequence involved the dwarfs holding a "lodge meeting" in which they try to think of a gift for Snow White; this was to be followed by **the elaborate 'bed building sequence'**, in which the dwarfs and the forest animals construct and carve a bed for the princess. This also was cut, as it was thought to slow down the movement of the story.

In the mid-1980s in Germany, when I was a child, my parents took to see me Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs at the cinema. I'm guessing it had just been reissued. *I distinctly remember both these bolded scenes.* A few years later, when we bought the VHS, I remember being confused and disappointed that parts of the story (namely those two rather funny scenes) were missing.

For the longest time I figured maybe I had been mistaken, maybe I had just made up those scenes in my head until I came across the Wikipedia entry quoted above.

Does a version exist where these scenes were added in? The quoted text above suggests that the bed-building scene at least is only half done, but at least to my younger self it looked pretty complete.

Comment: How is this a recommendation question? It's asking if there exists an alternative version with these scenes.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've seen questions asking about alternate versions of other movies, so I thought this was the right place to ask.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've edited the question per your request. It's so weird. I'm so positive that I've seen those scenes within the movie itself long before DVD featurettes were a thing but I can't find proof.

Comment: @E.T. I'm assuming that quote is from wikipedia, innit?

Comment: @Vishwa Yes, it is. Forgot to add the link in, I've done that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you saw was the 1987 *Golden Anniversary of Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs*

Here's a recording of the TV special: https://archive.org/details/99x20071116T1410190800

And in case that link stops working: https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_Anniversary_of_Snow_White_and_the_Seven_Dwarfs

> Disney's *Golden Anniversary of Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs* is a TV special celebrating the 50th anniversary of the film Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs. It originally aired on NBC on May 22, 1987 and would later reair as an episode of The Magical World of Disney on December 25, 1988.

It included these unfinished scenes, as well as a performance of the song "You're Never Too Old" written for, but not included in *Snow White*.

Comment: You know what, you might be right. It's possible that I saw the movie at some point and this TV special soon after, and my young brain combined the two. I don't remember the live-action sequences at all, which is odd, but maybe I found them too boring back then to pay attention.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a version exist where these scenes were added in?

### Apparently not.

From all available reports these sequences were never completed being removed from the movie at the scripting stage.

Rough versions do exist on Youtube for instance:

As regards availability, apparently these "deleted" scenes are available on the Walt [**Disney Signature Edition**](https://ohmy.disney.com/insider/2016/02/02/going-through-every-feature-on-the-new-snow-white-blu-ray/) of *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs* on Blu-Ray.

> **Deleted Scene**: Soup Eating Sequence (4:07) This is a roughly animated version of the famous soup eating sequence, which the animators toiled on (Neal Gabler’s Walt Disney biography said that as much as a year-and-a-half of work had already been committed to it) but was removed late in production. The character animation, even in this early form, was jaw-dropping.
>
> **Deleted Scene:** Bed Building Sequence (6:28) Another sequence, animated on a basic level, but removed from the film at a similar late date (this one is about the Dwarfs building Snow White a bed). Again, this is lovely and it’s wonderful that it survived all of these years.